# Generating random matrices with constraints

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, random

I would like to generate random $9\times9$ matrices which contain only the digits $1$ through $9$ (inclusive), each digit appearing exactly $9$ times.

How can I do so using Mathematica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Partition[RandomSample[Flatten@Table[Range@9, 9]], 9] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  7 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 2 \\
>  7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 6 \\
>  6 & 3 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 6 \\
>  3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 6 & 9 & 4 \\
>  2 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 7 & 4 \\
>  4 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 8 & 3 \\
>  8 & 9 & 1 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
>  3 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
>  2 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This works slightly faster than Henrik's solution, thank you.

Comment: Replacing `Table` with `ConstantArray` is faster for large matrix..

Answer (score 7):

```
a = Flatten[ConstantArray[Range[9], 9]];
Partition[a[[PermutationList[RandomPermutation[9^2], 9^2]]], 9]
```

Comment: Works well, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = ArrayReshape[RandomSample[Join @@ ConstantArray[Range@#, #]], {#, #}] &;

SeedRandom[1]
f @ 9 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  9 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 7 \\
>  7 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 9 & 3 & 3 \\
>  4 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
>  5 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 1 \\
>  3 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 5 & 4 \\
>  3 & 2 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 5 \\
>  8 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 8 \\
>  1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 2 \\
>  7 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
KeySort @ Counts[Flatten @ f @ 9]
```

> <|1 -> 9, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 7 -> 9, 8 -> 9, 
>    9 -> 9|>

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty fast:

```
Partition[RandomSample[Mod[Range[9^2], 9, 1]], 9]
```